# on premise integrated windows authentication get access token

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

We have a Azure Passthrough setup i.e Azure authentication is done on premise AD.

Here we have a on premise MVC application hosted in IIS which needs to consume application services hosted in azure. for this we have registered the application in azure ad as native and mapped the permissions to the services.

The hosted on premise application uses Integrated Windows authentication. 
we are able to get the access token by using the below code from visual studio debug mode i.e running on IIS Express.

```
var clientId = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";

string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/oauth2/authorize";

string resource = "https://ourdomain.sharepoint.com";  ///put id or url of resource you're accessing

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(); // By passing empty means windows Authentication

AuthenticationResult token = null;

return authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uc).Result;
```

But once deployed in IIS and running app pool with service account. we are receiving access token for the service account instead need to receive access token based on the user authenticated.

Comment: Have you checked the guide and accompanying github sample? https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-username-and-password

Comment: i have checked, the sample is for desktop app ..but my application is web application running on premise and is already using integrated windows authentication. When trying to get the access token from azure using above code it gets token based on the application pools service account.. need to get the access token for windows authenticated user